# c# Replace backslash in string

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am reading the contents of an XLS file. Some older versions of excel add what I assume are escape sequences within the cell that causes me problems upon attempting to create a SQL column of that name.

Example string I have to work with is passed as

> \0\0K\0\b\0Job

I would like to return this string as "Job". None of the replace sequences in the following job make a change and it returns as

> \0\0K\0\b\0Job

C# does not allow that string to be created manually without escaping it with "\\", which defeats the purpose of what I need.

Any suggestions?

```
public static string CleanupHeaders(string _Col)
{
   // Replace your @"\" parameter with double-escaped: @"\\"
   _Col = _Col.Replace(@"\\0K", "");
   _Col = _Col.Replace(@"\\b", "");
   _Col = _Col.Replace(@"\\0", "");
   return _Col;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Are you not allowed to do this Col.Replace(@"\\0K", "")?

Comment: @Robert It should be since @ already escapes it, don't really see why it wouldn't be working.

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra He doesn't need the double backslash, as he has the @ character prior to his string definition.

Comment: Your function appears to work just fine [as seen in this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8V7qwu), which accepts your exact input `"\0\0K\0\b\0Job"` and passes it through your `CleanupHeaders()` method to return "Job".

Comment: Can you show us your full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any suggestions?

I have one, since the `string` comes in as `"\0\0K\0\b\0Job"` your string replace methods `_Col.Replace` shouldn't need to use the literal syntax. In **C#** the `\` is an escape character and the following characters create an [escape sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

The issue is the verbatim string with the `@` syntax. Remove that and you get "Job".  See this working [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6mzGv1) - it has several demonstrations that will easily show you what happens. Take a look @ [MSDN's reference on string literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) for more details.

```
public static string CleanupHeaders(string _Col)
{
    _Col = _Col.Replace("\0K", "");
    _Col = _Col.Replace("\b", "");
    _Col = _Col.Replace("\0", "");
    return _Col;
}
```

There should be no reason to use them in this situation.

**Updated**

The *OP* altered the question a little, so here's an update [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JRwl4S).

Comment: Maybe the issue is that in the example they use Console.WriteLine(CleanupHeaders("\0\0K\0\b\0Job")). The input string should use @"" so the slashes aren't treated as escape characters.

Comment: Or as your example the Replace strings are using the slash as an escape. Strings in both places need to treated the same for the Replace to work.

Comment: @Marc, the asker specifically stated that his string comes in as `"\0\0K\0\b\0Job"` - but I updated my answer and .NET fiddle to explain it better -- thanks

Comment: @DavidPine  Thank you.  That was it.  For the others, the string in debugging (VS2015) had the single backslash, not the double.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the thing that's reporting the content of the string to you is reporting actual zero characters as `\0` for human readability.

Try removing the `@`s from your replacement strings there.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you provided should be working exactly as expected [as seen in this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8V7qwu).

**It's All In How It's Called**

Since you mentioned that your initial string isn't being changed, it's worth noting that your replace function actually returns a string and doesn't perform an inline replacement, so you'll need to call it through :

```
// This will set your original string to the result of your CleanupHeaders() method
yourColumnVariable = CleanupHeaders(yourColumnVariable);
```

If you do want to perform an inline replacement of your existing string, simply update your `CleanupHeaders()` method to use a [`ref`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) parameter to perform an update to the actual reference that was passed in :

```
// Notice the ref keyword
public static void CleanupHeaders(ref string _Col)
{
   _Col = _Col.Replace(@"\0K", "");
   _Col = _Col.Replace(@"\b", "");
   _Col = _Col.Replace(@"\0", "");
}
```

and then you could simply call it using :

```
// This will update the yourColumnVariable to reflect any changes made in the method
CleanupHeaders(ref yourColumnVariable);
```

You can [see an updated example that uses the `ref` approach here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O39Wlw).

Comment: Using a `ref` adds complexity, changes the signature and invocation of the method. Probably best to avoid that in this specific situation.

Comment: That's a fair point. I'm not stating that it's the ideal approach, I was just indicating that it is another option that OP *could* potentially use. Since we don't know how he/she is calling this to begin with or how they are trying to use it, I thought it couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a debugger, I would first of all suggest seeing what value the `_Col` string is when it's passed into your `CleanupHeaders()` method.

Depending where the string:

> "\0\0K\0\b\0Job"

came from; I would imagine it is already escaped when it reaches your code.

The string would look something like this: `"\\0\\0K\\0\\b\\0Job"` when it reaches your method.

I would suggest 1 of 2 things:

1: Replace all your `\` in the string with `-` or any character of your choice:

```
_Col = _Col.Replace(@"\\", "-");
```

And then replace your matching strings that now have the `-` prefix:

```
// Replace all your escaped backslashes
   _Col = _Col.Replace(@"\\", "-");

// Now replace your new prefix + values you are looking to replace
   _Col = _Col.Replace("-0K", ""); 
   _Col = _Col.Replace("-0", "");
   _Col = _Col.Replace("-b", "");
   return _Col;
```

Or

2: `\0` Is recognised as a character as it's escaped; so it's not being printed/output. Try changing your `.Replace(@"\0", "");` with `.Replace(@"\\0", "");` like so:

```
public static string CleanupHeaders(string _Col)
{
    _Col = _Col.Replace(@"\\0K", ""); // Replaces the exact already escaped \\ value.
    _Col = _Col.Replace(@"\\b", "");
    _Col = _Col.Replace(@"\\0", "");
    return _Col;
}
```